# Public ActionResult Delete(int id, brand brand) - Null brand object (MVC3 & Entity Framework)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, null-object-pattern

I am learning MVC 3 with Entity Framework and I have a problem with my delete action result method in my controller. I have two ActionResult methods for delete, one with [HttpPost] for submitting data to the database another for populating the view with correct record based on ID.

My problem is I have a null object in my parameter so When I try to commit a delete transaction it can't see the correct values because I have null object with null values.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using DBFirstMVC.Models;

namespace DBFirstMVC.Controllers
{
    public class BrandController : Controller
    {
        // Instantiate model of my database when controller is called
        //TestBradEntities db = new DBFirstMVC.Models.TestBradEntities();
        //
        // GET: /Brand/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            using (var db = new DBFirstMVC.Models.TestBradEntities1())
            {
                return View(db.Brands.ToList());
            }
        }


        //
        // GET: /Brand/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // GET: /Brand/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Brand/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Brand brand)
        {

            using (var db = new DBFirstMVC.Models.TestBradEntities1())
            {
                db.Brands.Add(brand);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        //
        // GET: /Brand/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var db = new DBFirstMVC.Models.TestBradEntities1())
                {
                    return View(db.Brands.Find(id));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return View(ex.ToString());

            }
        }

        //
        // POST: /Brand/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, Brand brand)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var db = new DBFirstMVC.Models.TestBradEntities1())
                {
                    db.Entry(brand).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Brand/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            using (var db = new DBFirstMVC.Models.TestBradEntities1())
            {
                return View(db.Brands.Find(id));
            }
        }  

        //
        // POST: /Brand/Delete/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id, Brand brand)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var db = new DBFirstMVC.Models.TestBradEntities1())
                {
                    db.Entry(brand).State = System.Data.EntityState.Deleted;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code with null object:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Delete(int id, Brand brand)
```

Brand is null and I dont understand why. For example

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, Brand brand)
```

Brand Parameter here in Edit actionresult has data in the object and not null values.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve this issue was add this line of code:

```
brand = db.Brands.Find(id);
```

This seems to find the correct data associated with the ID I passed to the ActionResult method as the int id parameter. I don't understand why Edit actionresult method works but this doesn't but this is an acceptable solution for me.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do it like that.  You're probably not binding the data when sending the post to the controller.  If you're still interested, post your Delete view.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem!

I put the line of code for find first:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id, Student student)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var schoolClient = new SchoolSrvManagerClient())
            {
                student = schoolClient.GetStudent(id);
                student.MarkAsDeleted<Student>();
                schoolClient.UpdateStudent(student);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("ShowStudents");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

View Code:

```
@model SchoolSTEModel.Student

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Delete";
}

<h2>Delete</h2>

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Student</legend>

    <div class="display-label">StudentName</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.StudentName)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">StandardId</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.StandardId)
    </div>
</fieldset>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" /> |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </p>
}
```

Comment: You may want to add some details (or comments), not just a hunk of code.